# PHP using ruby returning output (using metainspector)

Tags: php, ruby, linux

I'm currently creating a php page which does a ssh call with a `.rb (ruby)` file.

### `rb` file

```
require 'metainspector' 
page = MetaInspector.new("www.hln.be") 
puts page.image
```

When creating a php file with the following code (php):

```
$cmd = "ruby facescrape.rb";
$last_line = system($cmd, $retval);
echo $last_line . '
echo $retval;
```

this only returns value 1.

However 2 things :

1. When running the same command in ssh, it will print the page.image
   correctly.
2. When i change the rb file and for instance set as last line

> puts "test"

this value returns correctly with also print correctly with the aboven php code.

I don't get why printing the page.image works in ssh but won't work by using that php code.
Also tried using `exec()` instead of `system()`.

Thank you in advance!
Kind regards,

Kurt Colemonts